# Admob with javascript unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, unityscript

I have a game developed with UnityScript and I want to make `interstitial(admob)` in a specific action, like when the player was to die.

When I download package `admob` I found using `c#` but I need show `admob` in UnityScript.

```js
function diePlayer(){
  
  //something like tha 
  interstitial.show();
  
  }
```

Comment: Grammar/formatting changes

Comment: Write your code in c#.  Converting to c# really isn't too hard.  I converted one of my full games in under 3 hours.  unityscript isn't being used as much by developers and has become sort of depreciated over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have such an aversion to C#, you should examine [this article](http://www.41post.com/1935/programming/unity3d-js-cs-or-cs-js-access). It says how to establish synergies between UnityScript and C#.
However, I recommend that you examine the C # as a language is powerful and fast.
So, I recommend that you look into [this framework](http://www.appodeal.com/sdk/choose_framework). It simplifies interaction with the advertising.